# Duplicating lines using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have been trying to find an answer to this question for days now, however I simply cannot find it as most people use RegEx to REMOVE duplicate lines in a document... Well, I'm trying to do exactly the opposite, I want to duplicate a set of lines using RegEx and slightly change the duplicated line.

My issue is very simple;

I have many instances of the following piece of text:

```
["HP"] = 100,
```

and I want to achieve this:

```
["HP"] = 100,
["HP_Realistic"] = 100,
```

Since I have many lines of "HP" as portrayed above with varying values (I'm just using 100 as an example) I would need an automation for this process.

I am aware that you can create a new line by using "\n", but that is as far as my knowledge extends.

Is there a way of doing this with a RegEx expression? Or is it perhaps done better through multiple RegEx expressions?

Thank you in advance for reading my question!

Comment: It is not obvious what sort of "process" you are talking about.

Comment: I want to duplicate the first line (["HP"] = 100,) and then change the text inside the duplicated (2nd) line.

Comment: By what rule shall you decide what to change the text into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can possibly do it

**Regex :** `\[\"HP\"\]\s+=\s+(\d+),`

**Subsitution :** `["HP"] = $1,\n["HP_Realistic"] = $1,`

Working example [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1yDATp/1)

Comment: Hey just one quick question, what would I need to do in order to make it work with decimals?

Comment: Change Regex to `\[\"HP\"\]\s+=\s+(\d+.\d+),`